# Position react native popup at the bottom of the screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-popup-dialog

I am trying to display a popup in my react native app using the module found here:

https://github.com/jacklam718/react-native-popup-dialog

However, I would want the popup to appear only at the bottom of the screen. I have tried various things in popupStyle but the position of the popup always remain at the center. Is it possible to change its position to show only at the bottom of the screen.

**index.js**

```
import PopupDialog, { SlideAnimation, DialogTitle } from 'react-native-popup-dialog';
import { styles } from './styles';

....
<PopupDialog
  ref={(popupDialog) => { this.popupDialog = popupDialog; }}
  style={styles.popupDialogStyle}
  dialogAnimation={slideAnimation}
  height={150}
  dialogTitle={<DialogTitle title="Select options" />}
>
```

**styles.js**

```
export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    popupDialogStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
        marginTop: 100,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Issue #89: How to position absolute](https://github.com/jacklam718/react-native-popup-dialog/issues/89) you need to use either

```
<PopupDialog 
  containerStyle={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}
/>
```

or

```
<PopupDialog 
  dialogStyle={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 0 }}
/>
```